# Timeline Chart in Android

Tags: android, graphics, charts, timeline

I want same timeline chart in android its possible??[image]

Comment: If you got the answer, please accept the answer so that it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using webview and enabling javascript. Checkout the following android app which displays the google timeline chart.

https://github.com/huzaifaiftikhar/GoogleCharts

[sample of timeline chart in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDFWy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, please check the following link and implement yourself based on your requirement and render it in android Webview.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Comment: its possible  in android ?? above mentioned link only for java script??

Comment: In android you need to go with third party library like mpchart etc., or you need to load javascript file into android webview. loading javascript file in webview is possible.